# Expand matrix identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

What are the intermediate steps to show the following?

$$
(I+P)^{−1}(I+P−P) = I−(I+P)^{−1}P
$$

I'm looking at the lecture slides here: http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/g.ridgway/mil/mil.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(I+P)^{−1}(I+P−P)$$
$$=(I+P)^{-1}[(I+P)-P]$$
$$=(I+P)^{-1}(I+P)-(I+P)^{-1}P$$
$$= I−(I+P)^{−1}P$$